# python decorator proxy doesnt work

Tags: python, decorator

I try to create a trace decorator to keep track which method got call. 
let read the code first. code is written in python 2.7

```
class Decor(object):
    def __init__(self,cls):
        self.cls=cls

    def __call__(self,*arg):
        self.instance = self.cls(*arg)
        return self

    def __getattr__(self,name):
        print "attribute name of instance of class {}  = {}".format(self.cls.__name__,name)
        return getattr(self.instance,name)

@Decor
class Foo(object):
    attr1 = 10
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value

    def method1(self):
        self.method2()
        print self
        print "value={}".format(self.value)

    def method2(self):
        print "hi"


f=Foo(10)
print f
f.method1()
```

output:

```
1. <__main__.Decor object at 0x02758B90>
2. attribute name of instance of class Foo  = method1
3. hi
4. <__main__.Foo object at 0x02758C30>
5. value=10
```

I expected the method2 would get print as method1. Can you explain why method2 doesnt get print in detail?

I dont understand the output line4. it shows Foo object instead of Decor object. f is a Decor object and why is self a Foo object? please explain!

please give me a suggestion to fix this problem. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the `self` inside `Foo.instance1` is a `Foo` instance, not a `Decor` instance.

You can see this if you print out `f.method1` itself: it's a bound method whose instance is `f`:

```
>>> f.method1
attribute name of instance of class Foo  = method1
<bound method Foo.method1 of <__main__.Foo object at 0x10c641e90>>
```

Why? Well, you returned `getattr(self.instance, 'method1')`, which does the same thing as `self.instance.method1`, so it's `self.instance` that gets baked into the bound method.

So, when the `method1` code looks up `self.method2` (or `self.value`), it's looking it up on the `Foo` instance, so your code doesn't get run.

If you don't understand this, try reading [How Methods Work](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-methods-work.html). (And follow the link at the end to the [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) if you don't want to just accept that attribute lookup is magic.)

---

So, if you want `self` to be a `Decor` instance inside `instance1`, you have to return a bound method with the `Decor` instance, not the `Foo` instance. You can do that by creating one manually with [`types.MethodType`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.MethodType). (Or, once you understand descriptors, you can look up the function implementation directly and then call its `__get__` manually.)

For example:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    print "attribute name of instance of class {}  = {}".format(self.cls.__name__,name)
    attr = getattr(self.instance, name)
    if callable(attr):
        return types.MethodType(attr.__func__, self, type(self))
    else:
        return attr
```

(If you want this to work with classmethods, staticmethods, non-method callables like functions stored in the instance dict, etc., it needs a bit more sophistication than just `callable`, of course.)

Now:

```
>>> f.method1
attribute name of instance of class Foo  = method1
Out[26]: <bound method Decor.method1 of <__main__.Decor object at 0x10c7e9f10>>
```

So, when we call it:

```
>>> f.method1()
attribute name of instance of class Foo  = method1
attribute name of instance of class Foo  = method2
hi
<__main__.Decor object at 0x10c7e9f10>
attribute name of instance of class Foo  = value
value=10
```

Answer (score 1):

[My other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27455032/908494) explains why your existing code doesn't work, and how to fix it (although I'm not sure how *well* it explains it…).

But there's also often an easier way to do what you're trying to do: You can monkeypatch the class instead of wrapping it. Of course this means you have to use [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) instead of [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__), with all the usual caveats about accidentally recursively calling yourself:*

```
def Decor(cls):
    old_getattribute = getattr(cls, '__getattribute__')
    def new_getattribute(self, name):
        print "attribute name of instance of class {}  = {}".format(cls.__name__, name)
        return old_getattribute(self, name)
    cls.__getattribute__ = new_getattribute
    return cls
```

This may print out *more* than you wanted—e.g., during `f = Foo(10)`, it'll show the `__class__` attribute being looked up ([but not `__init__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-special-lookup)). You can of course filter out any names you don't want to log.

This also has a few limitations that wrapping and delegating doesn't. It won't work on old-style classes; you can't use it to dynamically wrap builtin or C extension classes; etc. On the other hand, it does mean that `Foo` has its own name, docstring, etc., rather than `Decor`'s, without you having to copy them over `functools.wraps`-style.

---

<sub>* Note that the docs say you should always call the base-class version for attribute access within `__getattribute__`, but in this case you want to call `cls`'s original version—which will of course be the base class version if `cls` didn't define one.</sub>